# How to update the state in react outside a render method using a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using a redux-form to submit data that user enters into a form-input to an api. The inputs of the redux-form are for editing the values of existing data in the form.So,what I want is to populate the input values of the form with the previous(existing) value which comes from the api.So,I used props to get the existing values and assign those values to the component state.And when the input changes, then I am changing the state for that input using **setState**. Now,the issue that I am facing is, since I am using redux-form, I am using **Field** component which comes from redux-form.So,this is how my **render()** method looks like:

```
render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
        <Field
          label="Title for Post"
          name="title"
          component={this.renderField}
        />

        <Field
          label="Post Content"
          name="body"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
  );
}
```

And the **renderField()** method which is used above looks as shown below:

```
renderField(field) {
    return(
      <div className="title-design">
          <label className="label-design"> {field.label} </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="title-input"
            {...field.input}
            value={this.state.title}
            onChange={this.onInputChange}
          />
          <div className="text-help  has-danger">
            {field.meta.touched ? field.meta.error : ''}
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

And the `onInputChange()` method looks like:

```
onInputChange(event) {
  this.setState({title: event.target.value})
 }
```

So,since my input is in the `renderField()` method,so when I try to type something in the input,I do not see the state updated(because my renderField() method is used as a prop and it is not in the render method,so state is not being updated), and that is the reason why my input is not working properly.I mean I am not able to insert or delete values in the input.

But,if I use the input as shown below inside my render method,it works properly as expected.

```
        <input
            type="text"
            className="title-input"
            value={this.state.title}
            onChange={this.onInputChange}
          />
```

But,I don't know how to pass the values with only input as shown above to a redux-form.So, how to proceed with this? Can anyone please help me figure out?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if I got it right. You want to update the redux with each imput? Usually what you do with forms is to have some kind of submit button that is used to send the form data to the redux. If you want to update the data on the fly you could use a reducer each time this.onInputChange is called if done as the last part of the code you posted.

Comment: @Rodius the main problem is with my input.So,what's happening is  at the beginning my input field is already populated with the existing value which I set in the state at constructor.But when I try to edit the input value,I am neither able to enter anything from the keyboard nor delete.This is happening because I set the value if the input as this.state.value and the value is not getting updated since the setState is not inside the render method,it is defined in the renderField method which is a prop to the Field component.

Comment: @Rodius and also the renderField() method is not being called when the state is updated.So,I guess this is the main reason why my input is not working properly.But I am not able to figure out how to find a way for this.

Comment: if you are using `redux-form` then why you are taking `value` props in input field !!! You automatically get your fields value in your handlesubmit function ...